# .hasOwnProperty... and value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ran across a small gotcha as an issue today with javascripts Object.hasOwnProperty.

I have a form that is building out properties on an object. The issue occurred with a select box that was selected a value and was the reset back to the default value or essentially left blank.

example:

```
var MemberSchema = {
  name: 'Name',
  country: 'Country'
  //ect...
}

function validateMember(member){
  for(var k in MemberSchema){
    if(!member.hasOwnProperty(k)){
       return false;
    }
  }
return true
}
```

The problem occurred by the form adding as soon as the select box was changed

`member.country = 'USA'`

But do to random user error occasionally the select box would be triggered back to

--Select Country--

which has an undefined value so the following occurred

`member.country = undefined`

Thus allowing the validateMember function to fail in detecting an actual complete member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize there are a several ways to fix this with the form itself as it is an angular binding on $scope but I opted for the following.

```
function validateMember(member){
  for(var k in MemberSchema){
    if(!member[k]){
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

What I am wondering if anyone sees a potential problem with this solution and if anyone has a better Object key:value validation method?

Thanks